# Using Two Cameras on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: pi-3, camera

I want to capture a stereo image with 2 Raspberry Pi cameras. Therefore, I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 B (which I bought from Cana Kit) and a multi-camera adapter module for Raspberry Pi(which I bought from Arducam).

[image]

I mounted two cameras to the "Camera A" and "Camera C" ports (on the top of multi camera board). Based on the camera selection configuration, which has been mentioned [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXnhJ.png), I only need to work with three pins of GPIO(Pin# : 7,11, and 12).

At first, I wanted to make sure both cameras were working separately and simultaneously. So, before using the multi camera adapter board, I checked each camera separately(I mounted them on the raspberry Pi).  Both were working correctly.

In addition, after using the multi adapter board, I checked them out separately.  They were working correctly(for example, at first I mounted camera A and ran following code to capture an image, then unmounted the first camera from  "camera A" port and used the second camera on the "camera c" port and took an image, they were working correctly).

However, the problem is :

When two cameras are on the board simultaneously, the first camera, which was plugged in "camera A" port, does not capture the correct image. Meanwhile, the second camera which was plugged in "camera c" works correctly.

Specific python commands for "camera A" as follows (pin 7= 0, pin 11=0 pin 12=1):

```
import RPi.GPIO as gp
gp.setup(gp.BOARD)

gp.setmode(7, gp.OUT)
gp.setmode(11, gp.OUT)
gp.setmode(12, gp.OUT)

gp.output(7, False)
gp.output(11, False)
gp.output(12, True)

cmd="raspistill -o capture_first.jpg"
os.system(cmd)
```

The captured image contains so much noise and artifacts and after showing this, the system would crash).

for the other camera, the code is same.  The only thing I changed was the pins' values(pin 7= 0, pin 11=1 pin 12=0)

I would appreciate it if someone would help me.
Thank you.

Comment: for other camera the code is same only I changed the pins value(pin 7= 0, pin 11=1 pin 12=0) you have used 0 twice here is this only a typo?

Comment: @steve Robilard, it is not typo, according to the configuration table of camera selection (mentioned link) the value of the pins would be changed to (pin 7= 0, pin 11=1 pin 12=0). By doing this, camera c can capture image correctly.